# Binding C-; in Emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

How can I bind a function to <kbd>C-;</kbd> in Emacs? I tried to use bracket notation with an escape character:

```
(global-set-key [C-\;] 'my-func)
```

and `kbd`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-;>") 'my-func)
```

Is it not possible? If so, then why acknowledge the existence of the chord (`C-; is undefined`)?

I am running Emacs 24.1.1.

Comment: Remember that the format of the string arg to `kbd` is the print format for a key description, i.e., what you see displayed by `C-h k`.  `C-h f kbd` tells you this, albeit indirectly and a bit obscurely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'my-func)` seems to avoid problems with the comment character and escaping.